# displaying date field in the value of a datefield form

Tags: datetime, coldfusion

I am using CF8 and MySQL 5.

I have a form with several date fields (one for each day and the form may have 10+ days of data on it) that the user can select different dates for and they all have different var names within a loop.

The default values for these date fields is null in the DB. I can insert a date into a DATE column in MySQL with no issues and have verified that the data is inserted correctly (using cfqueryparam DATE also).

I have the 'value' of the form datefield set to the variable name and can not get the value to show up.

The date updates to the DB fine every time it is entered, but when the form posts back to itself the date fields are blank (other non-date fields work fine and changes show up).

Then when I submit it with the blank date fields the value is set back to null in the DB (empty string in the form) since the form field does not pull the value from the DB.

The field name (ses#i#Date) shows up correctly (ses1Date, ses2Date, etc...) in the form with the right value when I dump it.

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#form.days#" index="i"> <cfinput type="datefield" name="ses#i#Date" value="#DateFormat(qGetUWHeader["ses#i#Date"],"yyyy-mm-dd")#" /> ....
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Eh.. So what is the question?

Comment: Did you check the HTML source to ensure that the fields are getting the right names?

Comment: Please confirm: The form posts back to itself. If you enter a date and submit it will write the data to the database but on redisplay of the form the date is blank again. Sounds like the data is missing from your query.

Comment: @Al: Yes, checked the html and it is populating the form correctly when I dump it out. When submitted the form posts back to itself and writes the data to the DB correctly. I have gone through the query over and over and it works outside of CF. Just doesn't populate the fields 'value'.

Comment: @Sergii: The question is, what the heck am I doing wrong since I can't populate the 'value' attribute to read a date in the code above?

Comment: just for debug purposes, try <cfinput type="text">.  If that works, then there's something wrong with datefield.

Comment: @Henry: thanks, I did that last night and still could not get it to populate.

Comment: cfdump the form scope, debug from there. :)

Comment: @Henry: did that too and no luck yet. The form var is populated correctly so I am pretty certain that the missing piece is from the query - DB - to populating the 'value' attribute. I appreciate everyone's help and I will update when I make some progress.

Comment: I thought u got DB working already.... ok, good luck debugging

Comment: Perhaps you can share more of the code?

Comment: @JS - Is "qGetUWHeader" a query? Because typically you supply a row number when using array notation with queries. ie qGetUWHeader["ses#i#Date"][rowNumberHere].

Comment: @JS - +1 to Terry's comment. Posting a bit more code would help.

Comment: Thanks again everyone for the help. @Leigh, your comment led me to my error. I am pretty sure that I have verified that my issue is my var name. if I use value="#DateFormat(qGetUWHeader.ses1Date,"mm/dd/yyyy")#" then it works. My issue is that since it is in a loop I need ses#i#Date, and when I put in value="#DateFormat(qGetUWHeader["ses#i#Date"],"mm/dd/yyyy")#" i get an error that 'The value class coldfusion.sql.QueryColumn cannot be converted to a date.' So I cannot use array notation. So I have tried many other variations and am still stuck with a simple variable naming issue.

Comment: So now the issue seems rather straight forward and I can't figure it out. If I put #DateFormat(qGetUWHeader.ses1Date,"mm/dd/yyyy")# as the value, it works. How do I write that so that the var is ses#i#Date for my loop without changing it to an invalid date or time string? I have tried dot, indexed, and mixed notation and get different errors that all say either it can't be converted to a date or is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reference dynamic column names, you can use array notation. But as I mentioned, you must supply a row number.

```
 #queryName["columnName"][rowNumber]#
```

If you know the query contains one (1) record, only, you could use the query object's "recordCount" property as the row number. Alternatively, you could hard code the row number "1".  (Personally, I dislike hard-coding). But any one of these should work.

```
<!--- pick ONE option ---> 
<cfloop from="1" to="#form.days#" index="i">
   <!--- syntax option 1 ---> 
   <cfinput type="datefield" name="ses#i#Date" value="#DateFormat(qGetUWHeader['ses#i#Date'][qGetUWHeader.recordCount], 'yyyy-mm-dd')#" />
   <!--- syntax option 2 ---> 
   <cfinput type="datefield" name="ses#i#Date" value="#DateFormat(qGetUWHeader['ses'& i &'Date'][qGetUWHeader.recordCount],'yyyy-mm-dd')#" />
   <!--- syntax option 3 ---> 
   <cfinput type="datefield" name="ses#i#Date" value="#DateFormat(qGetUWHeader['ses#i#Date'][1], 'yyyy-mm-dd')#" />
</cfloop>
```

If however, you are looping through *multiple records* in the qGetUWHeader query, you can use the query object's "currentRow" property as the row number.  But based on the field naming convention, I am guessing the query only contains one (1) record.

**EDIT:** 
I forgot about the initial nulls. You could apply a simple if condition, and only call DateFormat() if the query value is a valid date.

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#form.days#" index="i">
    <cfset dateValue = qGetUWHeader["ses#i#Date"][qGetUWHeader.recordCount]>
    <!--- if this is a valid date, format the value --->
    <cfif IsDate(dateValue)>
      <cfset dateValue = dateFormat(dateValue, "yyyy-mm-dd")>
    </cfif> 
    <cfinput type="datefield" name="ses#i#Date" value="#dateValue#" /><hr>
</cfloop>
```

Another option is to format the dates in your SQL. Then you would not need to use CF's DateFormat() function.  Just be aware that the new result would be a string, *not* a datetime object.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(ses1Date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS ses1Date, ....
```

Comment: @Leigh: that's a huge help, thank you. I will test this out first thing this evening.

Comment: Works like a champ! I went with option #3 which I should have caught on to after your earlier post - apologies. Thanks so much for the thorough explanation and options.

Answer (score 1):

Where is "qGetUWHeader" defined?

When a form is posted, all values will be posted to the form scope. Therefore in order to display a value from a postback, you should reference the form scope unless you're copying the value into 'qGetUWHeader'. Even though the correct date from the form is being stored in the form scope, you're displaying the default value from qGetUWHeader on post back, unless you're doing something there I'm not aware of. Then the next time you post your form, the default value overrides the prior entered value.

```
<!--- In order to reference FORM values, you must CFPARAM them first to define the default value. --->
<cfparam name="form.days" default="10">
<cfloop from="1" to="#form.days#" index="i">
    <cfparam name="form['ses#i#Date']" default="">
</cfloop>

<!--- Display the Form --->
<cfform action="#cgi.SCRIPT_NAME#" method="post">
    <cfloop from="1" to="#form.days#" index="i">
      <cfset thisFieldName = "ses" & i & "Date">
      <cfset thisFieldValue = form["ses#i#Date"]>
      <cfoutput>#thisFieldName#</cfoutput> <!--- For Debugging --->
      <cfinput type="datefield" name="#thisFieldName#" value="#thisFieldValue#" /><br /><br />
    </cfloop>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</cfform>

<!--- Debug --->
<cfdump var="#form#">
```

Comment: Dan, thank you very much for the feedback and the time. The form does submit to itself, but also calls a function that inserts or updates to the DB. qGetUWHeader is the query to pre-populate several fields if they exist when the user opens up the form. I have to use that versus the form object since I need the field pre-populated if data had been entered before (isn't a new form every time). I am pretty sure that 2 of Leigh's options will work and I will test them tonight and send an update

Comment: In that case, the only way for us to help any further is to see the source code of qGetUWHeader.